# Exporting CSV of time-series for every polygon from table of polygons

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

My question has a similar intention as in this link: [Exporting time series of multiple polygons to .csv. format table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273000/exporting-time-series-of-multiple-polygons-to-csv-format-table)

However, in my case, following this code, the table output runs for hours and then fails. I am doing this for a school project, extremely new to GEE and could be making silly errors.

I am trying to estimate the water quality of a few water bodies, the geometries of which I have as a table import(myPoly in the code below).

I need to export a time series of the band values from B1 to B5 for each of the polygons in the table(myPoly in the code below).

I am successfully able to export a .csv for one polygon using the code below.

```
var feature_geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[152.33970575255924, -27.555041715266274],
      [152.33972512360785, -27.55507189866278],
      [152.33974864709506, -27.555092138206774],
      [152.33976838530103, -27.555115340638235],
      [152.33979976776598, -27.55513612225267],
      [152.33982787718892, -27.555160307478587],
      [152.3398568409587, -27.55517391634846],
      [152.33988310356358, -27.555191307533534],
      [152.33991978430754, -27.555203490775874],
      [152.33995439458982, -27.55521975267031],
      [152.33998649311152, -27.555225647588358],
      [152.3400171895999, -27.555235843175478],
      [152.34005624881027, -27.55523845824814],
      [152.34009460494957, -27.555245502351152],
      [152.34010865812022, -27.555246111547888],
      [152.3406839153442, -27.55526396511705],
      [152.34072710914018, -27.55525986938896],
      [152.34077054865222, -27.555260077363187],
      [152.34078446061986, -27.555258213261332],
      [152.34156914104003, -27.55514318437435],
      [152.34199205237897, -27.555181651691527],
      [152.34205553080847, -27.555179438671836],
      [152.34211905665086, -27.55517903323108],
      [152.34212692410586, -27.555176949685123],
      [152.34213512873066, -27.555176663644694],
      [152.34219538347477, -27.55515881950017],
      [152.34225625321793, -27.555142699252606],
      [152.34226315111783, -27.555138750409775],
      [152.34227093907566, -27.555136444037643],
      [152.3423231738059, -27.555104389177178],
      [152.34237654217088, -27.55507383731013],
      [152.34238192143874, -27.555068337501407],
      [152.34238867280254, -27.555064194387068],
      [152.34242872960888, -27.55502048040243],
      [152.34247034845353, -27.554977928868823],
      [152.34247378089967, -27.554971315882597],
      [152.34247895825914, -27.554965665821168],
      [152.3425036486274, -27.554913772372693],
      [152.34253020510485, -27.554862608299867],
      [152.34253141751086, -27.5548554085329],
      [152.34253460875078, -27.554848701272384],
      [152.34254196736606, -27.554792759099758],
      [152.34255134762327, -27.554737055166008],
      [152.34255124628547, -27.554724581552886],
      [152.34253333867068, -27.553970991457973],
      [152.34253003667615, -27.553953146742987],
      [152.3425308622658, -27.553935078312687],
      [152.34251849392135, -27.553890767074545],
      [152.34251015865294, -27.55384572134672],
      [152.34250136615964, -27.553829404530607],
      [152.3424964664893, -27.553811850779955],
      [152.34249101348553, -27.553800351795616],
      [152.3421834185866, -27.553176074209468],
      [152.34215784879848, -27.55313937884634],
      [152.34213615731048, -27.553100770257625],
      [152.3421203870286, -27.553085617172872],
      [152.34210816445676, -27.553068076452668],
      [152.34207205170563, -27.55303917349878],
      [152.34203906014997, -27.55300747306692],
      [152.3420191436484, -27.552996828324574],
      [152.34200188144698, -27.552983012441533],
      [152.3419581003074, -27.552964202552257],
      [152.3419164348113, -27.55294193361053],
      [152.34189395743567, -27.552936644523356],
      [152.34187302967104, -27.552927653211807],
      [152.34182506509669, -27.552920433637816],
      [152.3417780422084, -27.55290936877626],
      [152.34175479314007, -27.552909856350183],
      [152.3417318656466, -27.5529064053112],
      [152.3416835355757, -27.55291135072272],
      [152.34163489827523, -27.55291237069524],
      [152.34162105354284, -27.552914592246776],
      [152.34082280384575, -27.553052836314944],
      [152.34077301008298, -27.55306817713331],
      [152.3407220582692, -27.553080161971984],
      [152.34070564988477, -27.553088929909627],
      [152.34068755312765, -27.55309450527163],
      [152.34064457415167, -27.55312156613553],
      [152.3405994259304, -27.553145691359457],
      [152.34058864505317, -27.55315370641969],
      [152.34020961746353, -27.55344352137888],
      [152.3402052483979, -27.5534479594163],
      [152.34019975004063, -27.553451266584393],
      [152.3401894698145, -27.553459783023747],
      [152.3396187810689, -27.55394586563294],
      [152.33959300712294, -27.553975072646328],
      [152.33956352384521, -27.55400137744232],
      [152.33954910819966, -27.554024818821677],
      [152.33953055173347, -27.55404584695574],
      [152.33951500514502, -27.554080273985168],
      [152.33949498252124, -27.55411283285313],
      [152.33948852574676, -27.554138911041978],
      [152.33947733266777, -27.554163697431107],
      [152.3394732509711, -27.554200604098988],
      [152.33946428282687, -27.55423682536616],
      [152.33946342957898, -27.55424927634419],
      [152.33945000045574, -27.554503386792554],
      [152.33945576354103, -27.554557167077725],
      [152.3394589488181, -27.55461111566492],
      [152.3394625173712, -27.554620192784938],
      [152.33946354284816, -27.554629762372247],
      [152.3394860200278, -27.554679975079274],
      [152.33950607503232, -27.554730987733734],
      [152.33951270635592, -27.554741989322267],
      [152.33968216642427, -27.555013989511846],
      [152.33970575255924, -27.555041715266274]]], null, false),
Sentinel = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2"),

myPoly = ee.FeatureCollection("users/martinomalerba/Poly_Ollivier_Grinham"),


var sentinel2mean = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterBounds(feature_geometry)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
  .filterDate('2017-08-01', '2020-11-11')
  .select('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6','B7', 'B8')
  .map(function(image){
  var B1_band = image.select('B1');
  var B1_band_mean = B1_band.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: feature_geometry,
    scale: 30
    }).get('B1')
    return image.set('B1_mean',B1_band_mean);
}).map(function(image){
  var B2_band = image.select('B2');
  var B2_band_mean = B2_band.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: feature_geometry,
    scale: 30
    }).get('B2')
    return image.set('B2_mean',B2_band_mean);
}).map(function(image){
  var B3_band = image.select('B3');
  var B3_band_mean = B3_band.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: feature_geometry,
    scale: 30
    }).get('B3')
    return image.set('B3_mean',B3_band_mean);
}).map(function(image){
  var B4_band = image.select('B4');
  var B4_band_mean = B4_band.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: feature_geometry,
    scale: 30
    }).get('B4')
    return image.set('B4_mean',B4_band_mean);
}).map(function(image){
  var B5_band = image.select('B5');
  var B5_band_mean = B5_band.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: feature_geometry,
    scale: 30
    }).get('B5')
    return image.set('B5_mean',B5_band_mean);
}).map(function(image){
  var waterThreshold = 0;
  //var area = image.pixelArea()
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI');
  var water01 = ndwi.gt(waterThreshold);
  image = image.updateMask(water01).addBands(ndwi);
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea()
  var waterArea = water01.multiply(area).rename('Water_area');
  image = image.addBands(waterArea);
  var stats = waterArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
    geometry: feature_geometry, 
    scale: 30,
  }).get('Water_area')
  return image.set('Water_area',stats);
});
// Time series at the identified points


var chart2 = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(sentinel2mean, feature_geometry, ee.Reducer.first());
print(chart2, "Sentinel2TimeSeries");
print(sentinel2mean)



Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: sentinel2mean,
  folder: 'GEE',
  description: 'FarmDamMean',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  selectors: (['system:index', 'B1_mean', 'B2_mean', 'B3_mean', 'B4_mean', 'B5_mean', 'Water_area'])
});
```

This is the output table I am able to generate:

[image: This is the output table I am able to generate:]

I need to generate a table with an added column to the left which is the `"ID"` of the polygon.
This is an example of the table [image]
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, you'll need to create a new image containing the "ID" of your polygons:

```
var feature_collection = ee.FeatureCollection(feature_geometry).set('ID', ee.List.sequence(1, 106));

var id_band = myPoly.reduceToImage({
    properties: ['FID'],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
}).rename('ID');
```

Then, you will need to add this image as a band into your image collection using this function

```
.map(function(image){
  return image.addBands(id_band);
  })
```

Please find the steps applied on your example code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Ffadwiputra%2Fshared%3AextractTimeSeries)

If you find this helpful, please kindly accept this as the correct answer :)

Cheers

Comment: Hi Adwiputra, thanks for your answer, the ID part works fine. But this still works only for one polygon. As mentioned in my question I need to do the same for all polygons in my table (called myPoly), and add them to the .csv with their ID. feature_geometry is one single polygon.

Comment: Hi Akriti, to achieve what you want, I would suggest merging your polygons into a single feature collection. After that, you can easily do what I provided in the answer.

Comment: The polygons are a single feature collection called myPoly

Comment: I see. Please find the answer as well as the code in the link edited. It would be easier if you had tidied up the code before asking the question. Good luck!

Comment: I have removed unnecessary imports from the code, also added an example image of the expected output. As mentioned, I need to perform the extraction of values for all polygons in the table of polygons called "myPoly". I am currently able to do it for one polygon called "feature_geometry".